# Are negative angles allowed?

Tags: geometry

Are in synthetic geometry problems negative angles allowed?
In many of them I needed to calculate something like 90°-A but A could be greater than 90°. Also the triangle natured is not specified. I have seen that the original solutions use a general way but are calculations with negative angles allowed ass well? It kinda makes sense for me thinking that if A>90° then if BB' is a height then B'CA is 90°-A=-(A-90°) so it goes in the exterior.
This may seem usual but I haven't   really cared about it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084420/when-are-angles-negative